# Where does evince save session data?

Tags: evince

In between sessions, evince remembers the current page, selected layout etc. Where is this data stored?

Answer (score 1):

Try looking in:

> ~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/

Comment: Also, see the following thread, which is where I got the info: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2244282

Comment: What exactly am I looking for in this folder? There seems to be nothing evince specific.

Answer (score -1):

You could also try `~/.gnome2/evince/ev-metadata.xml`. Information from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/346345/where-does-evince-store-its-per-document-state-position-etc).

Comment: This worked a few years ago, but is now out of date I believe. I don't have ev-metadata.xml at this path on 15.04